# Dividing 1.0/0.0: output is infinity

Tags: java

```
double d=1.0/0.0;
```

output is `Infinity`

```
double d=1/0;
```

output is `ArithmeticException`.

What is difference between between these two?
What is meaning of Infinity here?

Answer (score 6):

The first case is treated as a division on double and the later as a division on int and hence the ArthimeticException.

Here is what infinity means

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#POSITIVE_INFINITY

The division of doubles and floats is as per the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standards for floating point match which shouldnt throw an exception.

Comment: ok, but how i implemented dividing by zero with doubles?

Comment: Question seems to be "why dividing by double zero doesn't throw arithmetic exception, but dividing by integer zero does?".

Comment: To complement this answer. Check this tutorial on data representation that is very ilustrative: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DataRepresentation.html

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, division by zero is undefined, although it can be loosely be regarded as being infinity. (With a little more rigour, it's a number that is greater than x for any value of x.)

An IEEE754 floating point double (used by Java) has a representation of infinity.  That is the result of 1.0 / 0.0. In that sense, 1.0 / 0.0 is calculable since it takes place in floating point arithmetic.

An integral type has no representation of infinity, so an exception is thrown. `1 / 0` is computed in integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

floating point number have a way to code "infinity". So infinity is a valid value for a double variable. Integer variables do not have this option. So an exception is thrown instead.